# SNOWFLAKE-Convert an entire table to JSON?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Convert an entire table to JSON?

I have the following table [table1]:

[image]

I would like to convert all this into a new table and a single column with JSON format, is it possible?

Desired result new table [table2] :

[ table]
| NewColumnJSON|

```
{
  "[1]": {
    "Column B ": " hello 1 ",
    "Column C ": " world1",
  },
  "[2]": {
    "Column B ": " hello 2 ",
    "Column C ": " world2",
  },
  "[3]": {
    "Column B ": " hello 3 ",
    "Column C ": " world3",
  },
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Generating-a-JSON-Dataset-using-Relational-Data-in-Snowflake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this great CTE to act as our Table:

```
WITH fake_data(columnA, columnB, columnC) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'hello1', 'world1'),
    (2, 'hello2', 'world2'),
    (3, 'hello3', 'world3')
)
```

we can use this SQL:

```
SELECT columnA, object_construct('column b', columnb, 'column c', columnc) as obj
FROM fake_data;
```

then we can use [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html) to us the sub-objects:

| COLUMNA | OBJ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "column b": "hello1", "column c": "world1" } |
| 2 | { "column b": "hello2", "column c": "world2" } |
| 3 | { "column b": "hello3", "column c": "world3" } |

which we can wrap in [OBJECT_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_agg.html)

```
SELECT object_agg(columnA, object_construct('column b', columnb, 'column c', columnc)) as obj
FROM fake_data;
```

| OBJ |
| --- |
| { "1": { "column b": "hello1", "column c": "world1" }, "2": { "column b": "hello2", "column c": "world2" }, "3": { "column b": "hello3", "column c": "world3" } } |

Comment: Hi!! @Simeon Pilgrim
Really appreciated, I think with your recipe I'm getting closer to what I want.

Forgot to mention that in column A , the value can be repeated multiple times, it's not exactly a KEY.

When I try to recreate your code with column A (with repeated values) it repeatedly tells me that it cannot be duplicated, do you know how I can solve this?

thank you

Comment: Interesting. The problem with this update, is i don't think you originally asked for help, was sensible. But i told you how to do it. But your now discovering some downsides. But you have not shared the actual problem you have. But want this undtated problem solved. Which cannot be guessed. And is a new question.

Comment: Yes; you're right. I will create a new question to a new problem.
I will take your answer as accepeted. Tk