# Sending Email Notifications from Snowflake Using External Functions

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I Need to send email notifications through AWS SES from snowflake and I am able to send notifications. I integrated the snowflake with aws and tested. It's working

Here my problem is, I need to send the table content in the body(marked in yellow line) of email
What should I do ? help me please... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC7ZA.png)

Comment: Use a stored procedure, or similar, to dynamically construct your SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL command

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to convert a table into JSON, which can generally be thrown into an email body as text easily.

```sql
select HELLOWORLD ('from@email.com', 'to@email.com', 'subject-line', 'TABLE DATA: ' ||
    (
    SELECT object_agg(id, object_construct(
        'column b', columnb, 
        'column c', columnc)
    )::string
    FROM mytable
    )
);
```

Script/example inspired by this post
[SNOWFLAKE-Convert an entire table to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864782/snowflake-convert-an-entire-table-to-json)

You will need to modify the query based on your data, but the question doesn't include any information about the table you want to pull from.

If you don't have a primary key for structuring your JSON, you can just put each row into an array with this instead of the `object_agg`

```sql
    SELECT array_agg(object_construct(
        'column b', columnb, 
        'column c', columnc)
    )::string
```